# auth_request doesn't block return directive, can't return status?

Tags: nginx

A trivial scenario. We had the following location declared to test if the server is reachable:

```
location = /ping {
    return 204;
}
```

We have decided that we want to protect it with the same auth_request logic we have for other endpoints, which work and are contained within the same `server {}` block. We simply added the `auth_request` directive but both attempts have failed:

This one always returns 204, even when the auth_request returns 401/403:

```
location = /ping {
    auth_request /validate;
    return 204;
}
```

which is somewhat of a surprise, given [the documented behaviour for auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html), I assumed it would simply stop processing further directives:

> If the subrequest returns a 2xx response code, the access is allowed. If it returns 401 or 403, the access is denied with the corresponding error code.

A second attempt to directly return the auth_request's status directly also didn't work:

```
location = /ping {​​​​​​​​
    auth_request /validate;
    auth_request_set    $auth_status        $upstream_status;
    return $auth_status;
}​​​​​​​​
```

as it fails with

> [emerg] invalid return code "$auth_status" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:157

The problem seems related to my use of `return`? I have seen [nginx auth_request how to return backend status code](https://serverfault.com/questions/808810/nginx-auth-request-how-to-return-backend-status-code) but it doesn't appear to address my situation.

Comment: Good question and good answer.

Comment: Thanks for that @amn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return), `return`

> Stops processing and returns the specified code to a client.

Importantly, the "stops processing" does not occur at the point the directive is encountered, so the return always happens regardless of the subrequest's result.

The goal was simply to protect my `/ping` endpoint and this tiny modification works: [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) is of course subject to the `auth_request` and since the path `_` does not exist, it falls through when the `auth_request` passes, but returns 401 or 403 if it does not:

```
location = /ping {
    auth_request /validate;
    try_files _ =204;
}
```

Comment: A nuance to end all nuances. Sheesh Nginx, first "ifisevil" now "return doesn't return like you think it should". Thank you for the info regardless!!!